# AWS autoscaling policies conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I have 2 autoscaling policies in **AWS** one for **CPU** and one for memory restore when CPU goes high autoscaling adds one instance but as memory restored policy terminates that instance quickly

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem and the question you have?

Comment: conflicting Autoscaling policies with each other

Comment: please update your question to include a clear problem and a lot more context if you expect a response to help you out. Also include any related configuration of the services.  Please refer to this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use two different scaling policies** on an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling group.

They will not be aware of each other and will attempt to scale the group separately.

For example, if one metric is high and the other is low, Auto Scaling will trigger both scaling policies, which will cause instances to be added and terminated in a continuing cycle.

Comment: So you mean i need to create two groups one for memory and another for CPU right?

Comment: No, I means that you should pick only one measurement (CPU _or_ RAM, but not both) and only scale on that single metric.